# nil returned from dateFromString NSDateFormatter

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am trying to create a `NSDate` from some strings of dates I have.

Here is what I am doing.

```
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    NSLocale *enUSPOSIXLocale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
    [dateFormatter setLocale:enUSPOSIXLocale];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"];

    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    NSDate *deliveryETA = [dateFormatter dateFromString:deliveryDate];
    NSDate *createDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:shipDate];
```

`deliveryETA` is always nil with this string `2014-12-23T23:59:59` but createDate is always properly initialized.

Any idea why this is?

Comment: include the defenition of `deliveryDate`

Comment: Can you please provide more data(deliveryDate, shipDate) to your question that how you are getting the format and how you want to get?

Comment: `deliveryDate` is `2014-12-23T23:59:59`

Comment: Remember, the date format string needs to exactly match the format of your date string. Your `deliveryDate` string does not have a timezone in it so your date format shouldn't have any timezone specifiers in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `NSDateFormatter` for `deliveryETA` Like

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSLocale *enUSPOSIXLocale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
[dateFormatter setLocale:enUSPOSIXLocale];

// chanegn this line
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"];

NSDate *now = [NSDate date];

NSDate *deliveryETA = [dateFormatter dateFromString:deliveryDate];
// add this line
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"];
NSDate *createDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:shipDate];
```

tell me what happen...

Answer (score -2):

```
NSDate *deliveryETA = [dateFormatter dateFromString:deliveryDate];
```

for `deliveryETA` to have the value the input string **MUST** contain the format `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ`

Comment: The single Quote is required in the format. Any arbitrary character added in the Date, needs to be enclosed in a Single Quote.

Comment: Your answer is backwards. Since the string doesn't have a timezone, the format shouldn't have a timezone specifier. You need to make the format match the data.